# ¿Como crear una enumeracion con c# y un archivo xlsx?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Estoy realizando un ejercicio donde uno 2 archivos xlsx como los siguientes:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí] [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Los dos tienen el mismo numero de columnas, el detalle que tengo es que me gustaría que al unirlas el archivo que en el campo ID con "" se colocara le consecutivo de el ID que si tiene, al unirlos queda asi :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y me gustaria el siguiente resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para juntar los dos archivos lo hago de la siguiente manera:

```
public static void JoinFiles(string cfdisFile, string ticketsFile) 
    { 
        FileInfo cfdisfileInfo = new FileInfo(cfdisFile);
        using(ExcelPackage package1 = new ExcelPackage(cfdisfileInfo))
        {
            ExcelWorksheet worksheet1 = package1.Workbook.Worksheets[0]; // Cambia el índice si es necesario

            // Cargar el segundo archivo Excel
            FileInfo fileInfo2 = new FileInfo(ticketsFile);

            using (ExcelPackage package2 = new ExcelPackage(fileInfo2))
            {
                ExcelWorksheet worksheet2 = package2.Workbook.Worksheets[0]; // Cambia el índice si es necesario

                // Unir las hojas
                int rowCount1 = worksheet1.Dimension.Rows;
                int rowCount2 = worksheet2.Dimension.Rows;
                int colCount = worksheet1.Dimension.Columns;

                // Añadir filas del segundo archivo al primero
                for (int row = 1; row <= rowCount2; row++)
                {
                    for (int col = 1; col <= colCount; col++)
                    {

                        switch (worksheet2.Cells[row, col].Value)
                        {
                            case "ID":
                                worksheet2.DeleteRow(row, col);
                                break;
                        }
                        worksheet1.Cells[rowCount1 + row, col].Value = worksheet2.Cells[row, col].Value;
                    }
                }

                // Guardar el archivo final
                FileInfo fileInfoFinal = new FileInfo(ticketsFile);
                using (ExcelPackage packageFinal = new ExcelPackage(fileInfoFinal))
                {
                    ExcelWorksheet worksheetFinal = packageFinal.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Datos2");
                    ExcelWorksheet worksheetToDelete1 = packageFinal.Workbook.Worksheets["Datos"];

                    // Copiar contenido del primer archivo al archivo final
                    for (int row = 1; row <= rowCount1 + rowCount2; row++)
                    {
                        for (int col = 1; col <= colCount; col++)
                        {
                            worksheetFinal.Cells[row, col].Value = worksheet1.Cells[row, col].Value;
                        }
                    }

                    if (worksheetToDelete1 != null)
                        packageFinal.Workbook.Worksheets.Delete(worksheetToDelete1);

                    packageFinal.Save();
                }

            }

        }
        Console.WriteLine("Unión de hojas de Excel completada.");
    }
```

Espero me puedan orientar a como hacerlo, o una manera de poder guardar el último ID y de ahi poder incrementarlo para los siguientes.

Comment: Algo simple a considerar en tu algoritmo: `valorActual`, `valorPrevio`  ¿valor previo tiene número y valor actual está en blanco? asigna un +1 y actualiza las variables. Con esto ya tienes la pieza del rompecabezas que faltaba para completar la figura.

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo voy a implementar.

Comment: Un gusto colaborar, luego en la parte inferior agrega tu respuesta detallando lo que hiciste, serás el héroe de más personas que les ocurra lo mismo o algo similar. Saludos.